# Cordova: upload image and location to a database, and load the nearest images

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, phpmyadmin, phonegap

I'm Trying to build an app with Cordova. With the app you should take pictures, these pictures needs to be uploaded to a database together with the location where the picture is taken.
The app on default shows a x number of the most nearest taken pictures to your live location.
Beneath here i post the javascript code i have right now, most of the code is from Cordova self. Is it better to modify this code or start over?

I can now access the camera and take a picture, but how do i upload this picture together with the location to a database?

And how can load the nearest pictures from the database?

```
var Latitude = undefined;
var Longitude = undefined;

window.onload = function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){
    navigator.notification.alert("ready");
    document.getElementById("camera").addEventListener 
        ("click", cameraTakePicture); 
}

function cameraTakePicture() { 
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {  
       quality: 50, 
       destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL 
    });  

  function onSuccess(imageData, imageURI) { 
     var image = document.getElementById('myImage'); 
     image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
     getLocation();
     navigator.notification.alert(image.src);
  }  

  function onFail(message) { 
     alert('Failed because: ' + message); 
  } 
 }

 function getLocation() {
    navigator.notification.alert("start locatie");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPicturesSuccess, onPicturesError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
 }

var onPicturesSuccess = function (position) {

  Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  Longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  getPictures(Latitude, Longitude);
}

function getPictures(latitude, longitude) {
  //Load pictures which are the nearest
}

var onPicturesWatchSuccess = function (position) {

   var updatedLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
   var updatedLongitude = position.coords.longitude;

   if (updatedLatitude != Latitude && updatedLongitude != Longitude) {

     Latitude = updatedLatitude;
     Longitude = updatedLongitude;

     getPictures(updatedLatitude, updatedLongitude);
   }
}

// Error callback

function onPicturesError(error) {

   console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
       'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

// Watch your changing position

function watchPicturePosition() {

   return navigator.geolocation.watchPosition
   (onPicturesWatchSuccess, onPicturesError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cordova File Transfer Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/) to upload your photos to your backend service (DB). In FT Plugin you can add some additional headers, or properties e.g. LAT and LON properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specifically mention it, I'm going to assume you have access to jQuery inside your Cordova app.

Inside your `onSuccess` you have to make an AJAX call that submits the image and location to your PHP server. Below is an example:

```
var request = {
  'url': 'path/to/your/php/script.php',
  'method': 'POST',
  'data': {
    'image': image.src,
    'location': getLocation()
  }
}
$.ajax(request).done(function(response) {
  // request is done
});
```

Your PHP server script will have to take the incoming data and save it to your database.